# My custom sql query for getting a username giving me a warning and an error

Tags: customization, mysql

I am writing a custom query to create a link to a specific username. A user will be logged in and can then click on a link to that user name. I am getting a warning and an error running the query in php.

The warning is:

> Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/..../public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(72) : eval()'d code on line 22 and defined

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as a join as b on a.id = b.customer_id join as c on b.appointment_id = c.id ' at line 1

My query:

```
global $wpdb;
  //the query

    $currentuserid = wp_get_current_user();
        $havelesson = $wpdb->query( 
            $wpdb->prepare( 
                "
SELECT e.user_login FROM $wpdb->ab_customers  as a
join $wpdb->ab_customer_appointments as b on a.id = b.customer_id
join $wpdb->ab_appointments as c on b.appointment_id = c.id
join $wpdb->ab_staff as d on b.appointment_id = c.id
join $wpdb->users as e on d.wp_user_id = e.id
where a.wp_user_id = $currentuserid->ID
and start_date > now()
order by start_date asc
Limit 1
"   
)
 );
```

What could be causing the error and warning?

Comment: The point of `prepare` is that you put placeholders in your query, then pass those in as extra parameters, which you don't do. Hence the warning, it's complaining there is no second parameter because you never provided one

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell - Is there a better way to write the query or is this the best way and I should add the 2nd parameter?

Answer (score 3):

### The Warning

> Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/..../public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(72) : eval()'d code on line 22 and defined

It looks like there's been a fundamental misunderstanding of what the `prepare` method is supposed to do. You've provided a single parameter to the function, but it expects multiple. Hence the `missing argument 2` warning.

#### What Does `prepare` do then?

Imagine the following query that searches for posts with a particular title:

```
$wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title=$title" );
```

Something is terribly wrong with this code. It's horrifically insecure. To demonstrate why, consider the user searched for this:

```
$title = '*;SELECT user_password FROM wp_users WHERE username = "admin"';
$wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title=$title" );
```

Now we have an SQL injection attack. `prepare` is meant to allow us to insert variables while keeping the query safe from these kinds of values.

For example:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title=%s",
    array( $title )
);
$wpdb->query( $query );
```

Now our query is safe. Your query has this issue too because of the incorrect use of wpdb prepare. As a result, the following variables are wide open to SQL attacks:

- `$wpdb->ab_customers`
- `$wpdb->ab_customer_appointments`
- `$wpdb->ab_appointments`
- `$wpdb->ab_staff`
- `$wpdb->users`
- `$currentuserid->ID`

That's why all the examples use `$wpdb->prepare` and that's why you need additional arguments.

### The Error

Now that we know how to secure the query, that still leaves another problem:

**The query isn't valid SQL**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as a join as b on a.id = b.customer_id join as c on b.appointment_id = c.id ' at line 1

It's this `as a join` syntax that has the problem, it's not something I have encountered, and appears to be made up.

This is what a JOIN should look like:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

See W3 School for more information, and keep in mind that this isn't a generic SQL stack exchange, pure SQL questions such as this aren't best asked here

### A Note on SQL and WPDB

I get the overwhelming feeling that the original sin here was that all of this could have been done with date archives, author archives, custom post types, and custom taxonomies.

E.g. if you had used a custom post type for customer appointments, and set the author of those posts to the user who the appointment belonged to, then you would have gotten author archives for free, giving you:

- a custom `archive-customer_appointment.php` template
- Archives at `example.com/customer_appointment/`, URL configurable via `register_post_type`
- Author archives, and easy peasy URLs via `get_author_link`
- You could use `pre_get_posts` to filter it all so users only see their own stuff
- You could then use `WP_Query` and the entire `WP_Cache` toolchain would have automatically sped everything up
- Caching plugins and object drop ins would suddenly work
- Free REST API endpoints for your javascript
- A free Admin UI for editing and administering all this data

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for the detailed explanation. I will create a custom post type. Just a question, is it necessary to use prepare if the query doesn't take input from the user?

Comment: no, if you don't include variables in your SQL then there's nothing to prepare